# Метод для получения cookie возвращает undefined, вместо ее значения

Tags: javascript, cookie

В экспортируемом классе, по какой то причине, метод для чтения cookie возвращает undefined, вместо значения. В свою очередь, метод для установки cookie выполняется без проблем.  Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

P.S. Должен выполняться console.log('Окно уже было показано')

### Super-класс

```
class CookieUtil {

  constructor() {}

  mountCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    let cookieText = encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);

    if (expires instanceof Date) {
      cookieText += '; expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
    }
    if (path) {
      cookieText += '; path=' + path;
    }
    if (domain) {
      cookieText += '; domain=' + domain;
    }
    if (secure) {
      cookieText += '; secure=' + secure;
    }

    document.cookie = cookieText;
  }

  readCookie(name) {
    let cookieName = encodeURIComponent(name) + '=';
    let cookieStart = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName);
    let cookieValue = null;

    if (cookieStart > -1) {
      let cookieEnd = document.cookie.indexOf(';', cookieStart);

      if (cookieEnd == -1) {
        cookieEnd = document.cookie.length;
      }
      cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.substring(cookieStart + cookieName.length, cookieEnd));
    }

    return cookieValue;
  }

  unsetCookie(name, path, domain, secure) {
    this.mountCookie(name, "", new Date(0), path, domain, secure)
  }

}
```

### Экспортируемый класс

```
export default class extends CookieUtil {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._cookieData = {
      name: "backroad",
      value: 'true',
      domain: 'local.domain',
      path: '/',
      expirationTime: new Date('January 1, 2021'),
      secure: false
    };
    document.addEventListener('mouseleave', cn => this.isOutDocument(cn) )
  }

  isOutDocument(event) {
    this.sendWarning();
  }

  sendWarning() {
    if (this.readBackRoadCookie() === undefined) {
      console.error('Ошибка при чтении. Состояние куки: ' + this.readBackRoadCookie())
    }
    if (!!this.readBackRoadCookie()) {
      console.log('Окно уже было показано');
    }
    else {
      this.mountBackRoadCookie()
      console.log('Куки установлены');
      this.openModal();
    }
  }

  openModal() {
    const container = document.body
    let item = document.createElement('div')

    item.classList.add("modal-backroad")
    item.id = 'backroad'

    container.append(item)
  }

  mountBackRoadCookie() {
    this.mountCookie(
      this._cookieData.name,
      this._cookieData.value,
      this._cookieData.expirationTime,
      this._cookieData.path,
      this._cookieData.domain,
      this._cookieData.secure
    )
  }

  readBackRoadCookie() {
    this.readCookie(this._cookieData.name)
  }

  unsetBackRoadCookie() {
    this.unsetCookie(
      this._cookieData.name,
      this._cookieData.path,
      this._cookieData.domain,
      this._cookieData.secure      
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Функция `readBackRoadCookie` ничего не возвращает. Напишите `return this.readCookie(this._cookieData.name)`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо за внимательность, это работает. Напишите ответ, чтобы отметил:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
readBackRoadCookie() {
    return this.readCookie(this._cookieData.name);
}
```